# TSQL Count(Id) performance with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have a table with approximately 12 Million Rows and I need the total the number of rows which meet a certain criteria as per the where clause.  The query is run once a day outside of peak hours.

e.g.

```
Select Count(Id) from TableName where ColumnName = X
```

This is currently taking in the region about a minute to return the correct number of rows.  I don't know how I can improve the performance when a where clause is required in the above case.  On the database in question the Id,ColumnName is in a clustered Index.

Normally I would use the following Sql if I only wanted the number of rows in a table

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), SUM(row_count) AS rows
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
AND index_id < 2
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);
```

However I don't see any way of stipulating a where clause

The obvious solution is to increase the timeout as its run out of peak hours however, i would only prefer to do that as a last resort.

Thank you for your help

Ps SQL Server 2008

Comment: When was the last time index maintenance was performed on the table?

Comment: Generally done when it reaches 35% fragmentation last re-index was 28 hours ago, current fragmentation is 4.9%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select Count(Id) from TableName where ColumnName = X  ;
```

You have described the clustered index as "id, ColumnName".  If you want to use an index effectively, it needs to be in the other order.  So try defining:

```
create index tablename_columnname_id on tablename(columnname, id);
```

If `id` is never `NULL`, you can write the query as:

```
Select Count(*) from TableName where ColumnName = X  ;
```

This will save the `NULL` check on `id`.

Comment: >You have described the clustered index as "id, ColumnName". If you >want to use an index effectively, it needs to be in the other order.  That's what the problem was. As soon as I switched the index, it dropped to sub ten seconds.  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes for indexing you apply as Linoff answered

you can try is as well

Select Count(1) from TableName where ColumnName = X  ;